# Rademacher‘s Theorem and Baire category

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Is there a variant of Rademacher‘s Theorem where the smallness of the points of non-differentiability is measured in terms of Baire category instead of measure?

More precisely, let X be a separable Banach space and Y be a space with the RNP. Moreover, let $U\subset X$ be an open set and $f\colon U\to Y$ be a Lipschitz mapping. Is the set of points where $f$ is not differentiable a meager set?

As a partial question: Is something known about the above in finite dimensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not even in one dimension. Googling "not differentiable on a residual set" yields a citation of the paper F. Mignot, Contrôle dans les inéquations variationelles elliptiques, *J. Functional Analysis* **22** (1976), 130–185.

Comment: Thanks, the counter example is indeed given in that paper - it can be found in Remarque 3.